# Python Pandas df.mean() output not sorting dates

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

`import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('FinalNumber.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('DATE').mean())
df.to_csv('Output1.csv')`

Hello, I am trying to make a simple script that will take multiple dates and values and output unique dates with the values averaged. Whenever I try running this I get a normal output except for some occurences where dates are off

```
[enter code here][1]
```

Comment: We are not seeing any output (or input)

Comment: `df.groupby('DATE').mean().reset_index(name='mean').to_csv(....)`?